# Moving uploads directory above wordpress directory. UPLOADS location in parent directory

Tags: uploads, options, directory, constants

I will ask for help as I'm going nuts trying to figure out what is going on here. I've read many other questions but there is never a final answer.

I want to organize my WP installation in a different way:

```
public_html/
-> content/
|--> plugins/
|--> themes/
-> core/
|--> wp-includes/
|--> wp-admin/
|--> etc
-> uploads/
-> wp-config.php 
-> index.php
```

This structure is based and adapted from [this article](https://deliciousbrains.com/move-wordpress-root-subdirectory/) and [WordPress-Skeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton).

Everything is fine until the moment I want to specify the **UPLOADS** directory. If I didn't try to, it would be inside `content`. But in the moment I define it, it becomes a directory inside `-> core/`.

The behaviour seems to be erratic, as I had it working at the beginning, and then it stopped working. Cache is disabled. This is my `wp-config.php` (the part to be edited):

```php
/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 *
 * For information on other constants that can be used for debugging,
 * visit the documentation.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/
 */
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

define( 'WP_ENVIRONMENT_TYPE', 'staging' );
define( 'WP_DEVELOPMENT_MODE', 'all' );

define( 'WP_CACHE', false );

/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://staging.mywebsite.com/core' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://staging.mywebsite.com' );

define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );

define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/content' );

define( 'UPLOADS', 'uploads' );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

And there are two important WP options to mention as well: `upload_url_path` and `upload_path`.

```
upload_url_path = https://staging.mywebsite.com/uploads
```

The value for this first one makes sense, right? It's the URL I want for my uploads folder (outside `wp-content`, named `content` in my case).

```
upload_path = uploads
```

And then this value is supposed to be the same thing as the UPLOADS constant defined in `wp-config.php`. Default value is `wp-content/uploads`, so if I want the uploads folder at the same level as the `wp-content` folder, giving it the value `uploads` seems to make sense.

This can be argued, because I think it is also supposed to be part of the ABSPATH (the WordPress directory), and since the content directory has been moved above the ABSPATH the relative path may not be the same anymore.

Anything I declare in `define( 'UPLOADS', 'uploads' );` is being appended to https://staging.mywebsite.com/core/. So trying to navigate from there with something such as `define( 'UPLOADS', '../uploads' );` ends up as this:

```
https://staging.mywebsite.com/core/../uploads/2024/02/image.png
```

which... we don't want. It works though! But it doesn't look good and seems dodgy.

Is there any clear and concise way to **move** the `uploads` directory **above** the WordPress installation directory **and outside** the content directory?

Answer (score 1):

Now, do not ask me why, but the `UPLOADS` constant the `upload_path` option seem to work different.

While declaring `define( 'UPLOADS', '../uploads' );` generates this:

```
https://staging.mywebsite.com/core/../uploads/2024/02/image.png
```

Removing that declaration and filling the `upload_path` option instead with the same value `../uploads` gives a different result:

```
https://staging.mywebsite.com/uploads/2024/02/image.png
```

with the images being uploaded in the path I wanted and the media URLs well formatted.

### **This is the working setup** and I hope the behaviour never randomly changes:

##### **Structure**

Requires setting up a copy in the main directory of the index.php found in the WordPress directory.

```
public_html/
-> content/
|--> plugins/
|--> themes/
-> core/
|--> wp-includes/
|--> wp-admin/
|--> etc
-> uploads/
-> wp-config.php 
-> index.php
```

##### **Main `index.php`**

```php
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', true );
require( './core/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

##### **`wp-config.php`**

Only the important part, of course you need the rest of your file with your database settings and everything. **Do NOT declare the `UPLOADS` constant or it will mess everything up.**

```php
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://staging.mywebsite.com/core' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://staging.mywebsite.com' );

define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/content' );

// NO. DON'T. DO NOT EVER DECLARE IT. 
//define( 'UPLOADS', '../uploads' );

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}
/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

##### **Database options**

Most important part. And risky, as they may not always exist in the wp_options table, as well as they may be overwritten by the wrong value when migrating websites or restoring DB backups.

Remember to pay attention to them. If the value of any of them is different than an empty string, you will be able to edit them from `Settings -> Media -> Uploading Files`. If you are having trouble again with the uploads directory or URLs and they have disappeared from that settings section, is because their values have changed back to empty string or they have been deleted. You will need to use phpMyAdmin or any other tool to add/edit them again.

**The right values:**

```
upload_url_path = https://staging.mywebsite.com/uploads
```

```
upload_path = ../uploads
```

I hope this can help other people to not go insane trying to figure out why it isn't working, and I will surely be coming back to this as well.

Comment: Excerpt from https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/wp-config-php/#moving-uploads-folder - "*This path can not be absolute. It is always relative to ABSPATH, therefore does not require a leading slash*". Excerpt from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/ - "*If the ‘UPLOADS’ constant is defined, then it will override the ‘upload_path’ option and ‘WP_CONTENT_DIR/uploads’ path*". See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_upload_dir/ and you would understand how the uploads path is determined, and that `upload_path` can be a relative or absolute path.

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ! Thank you, now I understand what was going on. Basically, the setup I was trying to achieve is not achievable by using `UPLOADS` because as opposite from `upload_path`, the constant cannot take an absolute path. Which is making me wonder why would they choose this course of action instead of making two constants as we have for `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL`, allowing then to specify an absolute path.

Comment: Hi Gerard  I wished I knew why, but anyway, I thought you might want to check [this Trac ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48316), specifically [this comment](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48316#comment:33).

Comment: @SallyCJ I have already added my two cents to it, thanks! 